# AngularJS table stop sorting when in edit mode

Tags: angularjs

I have AngularJS table with CRUD operations and sortable header. When I add the new row to table the lines are jumping and the table is getting sorted while in edit mode.

I want to stop sorting while in the edit mode and should sort only after saving the new row. I searched online for fixing this issue but nothing helped yet.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<thead>   
    <tr>
         <td><input type="text" ng-model="main.search.Data1" id="myInput" placeholder="search for Data1..."/></td>
         <td><input type="text" ng-model="main.search.Data2" id="myInput" placeholder="search for Data2..."/></td>
       </tr>

       <tr class="table_header" style="background-color: blue;">
          <th><a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='data1'; reverseSort = !reverseSort"> Data1 <span ng-show ="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></th>
          <th><a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='data2'; reverseSort = !reverseSort"> Data2</th>
       </tr> 
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat=" code in main.Table | orderBy: Predicate | orderByField:reverseSort | filter:main.search"></tr>

   <script type="text/ng-template" id="dispay">
     <td>{{code.data1}}</td>
     <td>{{code.data2}}</td> 
   </script>

   <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="code.data1" class"form-control input-sm"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="code.data2" class"form-control input-sm"/></td>
   </script>
</tbody>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
//add new row
$scope.addNew = function(data) {
  $scope.Table.unshift({
    data1: "",
    data2: ""
  });
  console.log($scope.table);
};

//Edit the row
$scope.edit = function(data){
  $scope.selected = angular.copy(data);
  $scope.backuplist = angular.copy($scope.table);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is correct because on addNew you add 1 empty record in apply cycle which then will reorder again the list.

You have 2 ways to go :
1) When Adding new Item, create sperate object and upon submit add it in the list:

```
 $scope.addNew = function(data) {
  $scope.newItem ={
    data1: "",
    data2: ""
  };
};

$scope.save = function() {
  $scope.table.push($scope.newItem);
};
```

Like this there is speration of concerns and not to mingle the main list.

Or if you still want to add it in main list directly which i dont recommend you can implement your custom filter which keeps always the empty data at the top - In your predicate Method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr class="table_header" style="background-color: blue;">
          <th><a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='data1'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" ng-disabled="setTrueFalse"> Data1 <span ng-show ="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></th>
          <th><a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='data2'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" ng-disabled="setTrueFalse"> Data2</th>
       </tr>
```

---

```
$scope.setTrueFalse = true/false
```

MAke use of ng-disabled.. Set it to true when you do not want to sort the values and vice versa